# Pass variable from python script 2.4 to 2.7

Tags: python

How do I pass a variable between two python scripts which both use different Python version interpreters? For example,

python-script-2.4 contains variable X
return X to python-script-2.7 for manipulation

I have tried doing this but the value returned is '0'.

Comment: What do you mean by manipulation? Some sort of global shared variable?

Comment: How are you running your two python scripts? Is one of them launching the other (e.g. using the `subprocess` module), or are you doing something more complicated?

Comment: I can only think of serializing the var x (using pickle) in python 2.4 and accessing in python 2.7 script.

Comment: so in python-script 2.7 pass 'username' to python-script 2.4 in the commandline:

def getFacultyInLDAP(username): faculty = os.system("python ldap-test.py "+username)

In python-script 2.4 return value of faculty from username: ...do a query based on username

return faculty

I was thinking of serilizing but thought it would be nicer and possibly faster to pass a variable if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand, you call a already existing Python2.4 script from a Python2.7 script, by using os.system().

Firstly, you should consider [Replacing os.system()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) in Python2.7 documentation.
But the limit of this method is that you only get the return code of your call (so you must look in your 2.4 script to ensure that return code are properly used when any error occurs...).

Secondly, if you need to know what was written of stdout and stderr, use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) :

```
#!/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command = 'read INPUT ; echo $INPUT on stdout && echo 1>&2 "Here is stderr"'
process = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate("Hello world")
print(out)
print("-------")
print(err)
```

Comment: Please validate my answer if it correspond to your needs ;)